# Can hours at an FAA flightschool be credited to an EASA PPL?

Tags: faa-regulations, easa-regulations, ppl, easa

Does anyone know if it's possible to put FAA flight school hours towards an EASA (UK/CAA) PPL?

I've heard answers from "NO" to "Of course" and everything in between, but am struggling to find any documentation that gives a definitive answer one way or another.

From what I can see FAA hours can't be used for credit towards specific training but they can be credited towards the 45 hours total time needed for the license. If anyone has links to appropriate documentation I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that "flight school hours" means flight time then [CAP 804](http://www.caa.co.uk/application.aspx?catid=33&pagetype=65&appid=11&mode=detail&id=6412) suggests yes:

> **3.6 Logging of Flight Hours gained in the USA**   Some flight hour recording practices allowable in the USA do not comply with European
>   and UK requirements. In particular:
>
> - 2 pilots flying together in a single pilot aircraft both claiming P1    hours;
> - One pilot accompanying another on newsgathering or traffic    control flights and claiming P1/PIC when they have not acted as Captain or signed for the aircraft.
>
> Flying hours of this nature cannot be credited towards the
>   requirements for Part-FCL or UK Licences.

The last sentence implies that if hours logged in the US *do* comply with "European and UK requirements" then they can be credited towards licenses. If you need something more detailed and explicit then it may be easiest to ask the CAA directly.

Comment: Thanks for the info, CAP804 looks promising. I've already asked the CAA but their responses are useless. First person I talked to said they didn't know, but probably it is possible. Second said they didn't know and probably it is not possible! I'll try them again and see if I have better luck.

Comment: @os1 Did you ever find out? If so, might you be willing to post a self-answer with what you found out, for the benefit of others?