# Should I record my helicopter and autogyro time in separate logbooks?

Tags: faa-regulations, easa-regulations, logging

I have been flying autogyros for some years now, and I am out to do my license on UL helicopters.

I bought a new logbook to log all time in helicopters separately from autogyros. Is that correct?

In a few days I will also be taking some lessons in an R22. That's not even UL anymore. Do I have to get another logbook for all flying of non-UL aircraft? Would I log it all in the same logbook?

Comment: Which country are you adding about? But it's usually easiest and best to log everything in one logbook. And online logging tools make it really easy to track all your flights and still easily calculate and print out whatever totals you need.

Comment: I usually fly in Costa Rica where I have most of my time logged. I'll be doing my UL helicopter license in Italy, and the flight in the R22 will be in Spain... I usually use ZuluLog, but for authorities I need also a good logbook.

Comment: If you're flying in multiple countries, [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/27737/62) might be helpful. FWIW, I have a single physical logbook and an electronic one. For checkrides or whatever, I print a report from the electronic logbook and I also show (or am prepared to show) the examiner my physical book if he wants to look at it. If it's a report to send to someone, I scan my physical book and send the pages with the electronic report. That covers every scenario I've had so far, but you may have other needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the United States, except for that time which is used for certification or currency, the FAA permits you to log your time however you like, or even not log it at all.  That means that **you can do pretty much whatever you feel like**.

That said, here are my personal recommendations in order of how much I support them:

1. Get a [digital pilot logbook](https://www.google.com/search?q=electronic%20pilot%20logbook). Log everything in it.
2. Get a [professional pilot logbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001MT32QC) with plenty of space for various categories and classes of aircraft. Copy all of your records from your old logbooks into it. Archive your old logbooks in a safe location. Use your new logbook for everything from here on.
3. Get a professional pilot logbook with plenty of space for various categories and classes of aircraft. *Don't* copy all the records from your old logbooks into it, just carry forward the totals. Archive your old logbooks in a safe location. Use your new logbook for everything from here on.
4. Get one logbook for each category/class of aircraft you intend to fly. Log your time in whichever logbook is appropriate. Remember which logbook is which. Keep them all easily accessible rather than storing them in a safe location. Worry about whether you lost one. Have a complicated system of adding up your totals from various logbooks. Make it difficult to look up flights chronologically. Feel sad.

Comment: Option 4 is... amusing.

Comment: 1. I use ZuluLog, but sometime at authorities I need to present my logbook :) 2. Would love to, because I would also 'correct' some thing I didn't logged 100% correct in the past, but have a lot of signs and stamps in my most used one 3. I think I'll stick to that option, and have parallel ZuluLog for easy access to totals of different ratings 4. Thanks for making me laugh! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to make sure your flight time was differentiated into category and class of aircraft.  Most logbooks have a blank category on their pages; just fill in ULTRALIGHT or UL in that column and add your hours that way.

Now some of those flights can be logged under the columns for PIC, Cross Country flight time, dual instruction, takeoff and landings, etc. as well in the new logbook and can count towards some hour requirements for another certificate.  Reference [14 CFR Part 61](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=075ad164248525b0b5751d2be5c41787&mc=true&node=pt14.2.61&rgn=div5) for specific requirements

Comment: Until now I haven't been differentiating because I was only flying UL Gyroplane, where I've logged PIC, XC, and instruction time. And I cannot add anymore the UL column because the book is closed already to certain pages and authorities have copies of if. So should I log then everything not UL in a different book?Should I log the UL heli in the same logbook as the Autogyro UL?

Comment: You can keep separate logbooks if you like or it's easier; A lot of pilots get multiple logbooks over the span of their careers.

Answer (score 1):

There are no regulations governing how many logbooks you may use, nor their exact construction.  If it is easier for you to manage your time with multiple logs, that is just fine.

If you need a flight review entry, you can always photo copy that entry in one book, and clip or tape a copy into a different book.

Personally, when instructing, I use a "critique sheet" which I review with the student at the end of the flight, and we both sign. That sheet becomes my log entry. For other types of flights I may use a traditional log book. While I have several, I avoid the large professional books, because of their size and weight.